# Kubernetes Dashboard not working after configuring it

Tags: kubernetes

I installed a single node Kubernetes Cluster Using Flannel on my server:

```
https://gist.github.com/BeerOnBeard/ebe63521607aa0db3851c39a5760489b
```

After the installation I can't get the dashboard running.
The External IP is pending and None.

Version:
kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.1", GitCommit:"5e58841cce77d4bc13713ad2b91fa0d961e69192", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-12T14:18:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:53:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Dashboard:

```
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get svc
NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP      10.106.250.241   <none>        8000/TCP        3d4h
kubernetes-dashboard        LoadBalancer   10.99.69.152     <pending>     443:31109/TCP   3d4h
```

If I access the IP address:

```
https://IP_ADDRESS:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

I get:

```
    {
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"https:kubernetes-dashboard:\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get resource \"services/proxy\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "https:kubernetes-dashboard:",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Checking the pods:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system            coredns-558bd4d5db-g2xj9                     1/1     Running   1          3d4h
kube-system            coredns-558bd4d5db-k5q6q                     1/1     Running   1          3d4h
kube-system            etcd-dyd-001                                 1/1     Running   1          3d4h
kube-system            kube-apiserver-dyd-001                       1/1     Running   1          3d4h
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-dyd-001              1/1     Running   1          3d4h
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-lv6hv                        1/1     Running   1          3d4h
kube-system            kube-proxy-vssrp                             1/1     Running   1          3d4h
kube-system            kube-scheduler-dyd-001                       1/1     Running   1          3d4h
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-778b77d469-2p7dl   1/1     Running   1          136m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-68f7c6c68f-hv5v6        1/1     Running   1          136m
```

I tried to fix it with:

```
kubectl delete clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

and I get:

```
namespace/kubernetes-dashboard unchanged
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard unchanged
service/kubernetes-dashboard unchanged
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs unchanged
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf configured
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder unchanged
configmap/kubernetes-dashboard-settings unchanged
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard unchanged
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard configured
service/dashboard-metrics-scraper unchanged
deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper configured
```

I really don't get it. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608533/kubernetes-error-from-server-forbidden-user-systemanonymous-cannot-list-n

Comment: Hello @dev. Does the above source help?

Comment: Sadly not, I wiped all and im trying again.

Comment: I see. Please let us know if the problem persists after the second try.

Comment: Yes still can't do it. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your RBAC configuration is incorrect. Take a look at this error:

```
  "message": "services \"https:kubernetes-dashboard:\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get resource \"services/proxy\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"kubernetes-dashboard\""
```

It means that you need to create a `ClusterRole` to grant permissions to `kubernetes-dashboard` and bind it to `system:anonymous` user.

The `ClusterRole` could look like this:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services/proxy"]
  resourceNames: ["https:kubernetes-dashboard:"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
- nonResourceURLs: ["/ui", "/ui/*", "/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/*"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

And a corresponding `ClusterRoleBinding` would look like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: system:anonymous
```

Apply these configs into your cluster and check the results.